# How do I remove a rank on MW3 title from another Call of Duty game?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

On MW3, I have the Black Ops rank icon under my name on the title but I don't want it there. I want to clear the icon so it's an empty slot as if I never played Black Ops.  How do I remove the rank?

Comment: OK on mw3, I have the black ops rank icon under my name on the title but I don't want it there, I want to clear the icon so it's an empty slot as if I never played black ops

Comment: How about you be just a little more patient? It's not even been an hour since you asked, Europeans are at school/work, the US is likely still asleep.

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? It doesn't have any effect other than the picture does it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove it once it's linked in your account.

Comment: That'd be what I expected, what logical reason is there for wanting to remove it anyways...